# Power (exponentiation) and other math function support in SPARQL

Tags: math, sparql, exponentiation

I am trying to write a SPARQL query where I want to filter on the square of something, but I am simply unable to figure out how to square a number (*x*<sup>2</sup>) (except by multiplying it with itself, of course). I guessed a square root function called `math:sqrt()` which works, yet nothing like `math:pow` seems to exist.

How do I get the square of something in SPARQL and, more importantly, where can I read about it and other math functions such as `math:sqrt` in SPARQL?

Note: This is related to my previous question: [Reverse wikipedia geotagging lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400717/reverse-wikipedia-geotagging-lookup) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's now a few years later and the [SPARQL 1.1 Query Language](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) has been published.  It includes many more built-in functions than the original SPARQL query language.  In addition to lots of functions on strings, RDF terms, &c., there are a number of numeric functions (the section numbers indicate the section in the linked standard):

> - 17.4.4 [Functions on Numerics](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-numerics)
>
>   - 17.4.4.1 [abs](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-abs)
>   - 17.4.4.2 [round](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-round)
>   - 17.4.4.3 [ceil](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-ceil)
>   - 17.4.4.4 [floor](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-floor)
>   - 17.4.4.5 [RAND](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#idp2130040)

There's still no `square` function here, and the quickest way to implement that will be using `*`, so [laalto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1404420/1281433) still stands.  The operators that SPARQL supports are described in [17.3 Operator Mapping](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#OperatorMapping), and for XPath arithmetic is still just the set of `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/`.

Answer (score 3):

SPARQL supports some XPath arithmetic functions such as `+ - * /`. They are described in the [SPARQL spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#OperatorMapping).

The power function is not supported by the spec. And in any case `x*x` is more efficient way to compute squares than `pow(x,2)` would be.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. What about specification of other math functions, such as the square root (math:sqrt seems to work fine) and the trigonometric functions sin, and cos? I updated the question a bit.

Comment: Those would be implementation-specific extensions, not part of the core SPARQL.

Comment: Where would I find documentation on these implementation-specific extensions?

Comment: Well, start with your SPARQL query engine documentation. I cannot read your mind and don't know which one you are using.