# Power function in SPARQL

Tags: math, sparql, pow, cascade-notation

Does anybody know if there is any power function added for SPARQL?

My quick-fix is using BIND and string process but it's not optimal at all:

```
?contract part:price ?price_E ;
    part:Currency ?currency .

BIND(strafter(str(?price_E), "E") as ?E)
BIND(replace(strbefore(str(?price_E), "E"), "\[.\]", "") as ?nodot)
BIND(substr(?nodot, 0, xsd:integer(?E)+2) as ?first)
BIND(substr(?nodot, xsd:integer(?E)+2, 2) as ?second)
BIND(concat(?first, ".", ?second) as ?price)
```

Example of input and output data:
Input 1.51535E3
Output 1515.35

Comment: Maybe you can explain why you need to do that. This reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rDOUBLE seems to suggest that `mmmEnnn` and `mmmennn` are recognized as floating point numbers; it seems like you don't have to do that parsing. I think it would help others understand if you explain what else is happening here that makes it necessary.

Comment: I also don't get the purpose of this conversion, rendering happens on the client side, handling and formatting scientific notation should be capable by any programming language.

Comment: That said, you could always convert it to `xsd:decimal` which doesn't have the scientific notation: `BIND(xsd:decimal(?price_E) AS ?price_E_decimal)` - indeed, for larger numbers this conversion might fail, as 32bit vs 64bit. But I assume for prices this would never be an issue

Comment: Casting decimal to double is safe up to 15 significant decimal digits. A 32 bit number 10 digits. An unsigned 64 bit number is 20 digits.

Comment: Somehow I didn't think of converting it to xsd:decimal, just tried xsd:float (*facepalm*).. Thank you for your comments! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, the answer is no. As of SPARQL 1.1, the current W3C version, [there is no exponentiation operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401401/power-exponentiation-and-other-math-function-support-in-sparql). You can accomplish it with repeated multiplication (`x*x`) as in:

```
(COUNT(?items)*COUNT(?items)
```

However, in your example, it is not clear that you actually need to do any arithmetic. The input `1.51535E3` is in fact already equal to `1515.35` because it is valid scientific notation, which SPARQL supports.